# How can i use the "edges" of a dynamic 2D array as a way to tell my program they are out of limit

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I will try my best to explain as well as i can what i mean and what my goal is, sorry if I'm failing to get my point through.

Lets say i have this output when i run my code:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
   _________________________
1 | .  .  .  $  .  .  .  .
2 | .  .  .  .  .  .  #  .
3 | .  #  .  .  .  .  .  .
4 | .  .  .  .  4  .  .  .
5 | .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
6 | 5  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
7 | .  .  5  .  #  .  .  .
8 | .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

My code reads 2 dimensions given by the user and then using malloc it gives me this dynamic 2d array.
The little '$' character is the player and the array is the level in which he is allowed to move, all my code that can "move" the player works perfectly fine, the player can collect the random numbers in the board which represent the value of a diamond he finds and if a user wants to move for example 4 spaces in a direction and at the 3d space there is the "#" symbol the character "$" stops and prints a message how many positions he moved before stopping in front of the obstacle. I want to achieve the exact same thing but with the edges of the board, for example in the output i am presenting above, "$" is sitting in the position [1][4] and if a user tries to move "up" in the board there is clearly no more  spaces to move so i want to show a message saying just that.

This is the recursive function that gets called when the user wants to move up:

```
int Up(int **D_Board)
{
    int column_pos, row_pos, stop;
    column_pos = Current_Position_Column(D_Board);
    row_pos = Current_Position_Row(D_Board);
    moving++;
    if (moving <= moves)
    {
        if (D_Board[column_pos - 1][row_pos] == '.' || D_Board[column_pos - 1][row_pos] == ' ')
        {
            D_Board[column_pos][row_pos] = ' ';
            column_pos = column_pos - 1;
            D_Board[column_pos][row_pos] = '$';
            Up(D_Board);
        }
        else if (D_Board[column_pos - 1][row_pos] == '#')
        {
            D_Board[column_pos][row_pos] = '$';
            stop = moving - 1;
            moving = moves;
            printf("\nHit an obstacle...\n\nYou only moved %d positions.\n\n", stop);
        }
        if (D_Board[column_pos - 1][row_pos] >= 0 && D_Board[column_pos - 1][row_pos] <= 9)
        {
            diamonds = diamonds + D_Board[column_pos - 1][row_pos];
            D_Board[column_pos][row_pos] = ' ';
            column_pos = column_pos - 1;
            D_Board[column_pos][row_pos] = '$';
        }
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

If i add the conditions i use when it encounters "#" in the code but instead i define the top row as D_Board[0][row_pos] the code never enters that condition and exits my main loop that constantly asks the player to give inputs and i cant figure out why, i have tried some things without success for example:`if (column_pos == 0){do stuffs};` or `if(D_Board[column_pos-1][row_pos] == D_Board[0][row_pos]){do stuffs};`

Comment: You haven't shown the things that involve testing the array indices that you allude to at the bottom of the post. The code only tests the array content. One thing sometimes done is to put a hidden "edge guard" around the array, making it 2 elements bigger in each direction.

Comment: @WeatherVane making a hidden edge guard sounds like a simpler solution than my approach, is there an example of how you would implement that on any dynamic 2d array, would be a great help.

Comment: What happens if you make the matrix (n+2)*(n+2) and fill the outer edges with "#"? Does you code adapts to this because it sees obstacles?

Comment: @Fra93 exactly that: make the array bigger, and place "no-go" `'#'` characters around the edge.

Comment: @Fra93 that sounds like a great solution and i think i can picture now better what Weather suggested, thank you.

Comment: Why would you even use recursion for this? And why not use real 2D arrays instead of `int **D_Board`? Write fast executing, readable code instead of this needlessly complex thing.